# Using Company of Heroes mods on Mac

Tags: mods, macos, company-of-heroes

I want to use a mod for Company of Heroes (specifically [Modern Combat](http://www.moddb.com/mods/company-of-heroes-modern-combat)) and am not sure how to install and use a mod on the Mac version of Company of Heroes. It is not a Steam game, it is downloaded from the Mac app store. So, is it possible to mod CoH on the Mac, and if so, how does one do it?

**EDIT**

I have also tried copying all the files (`BattleOfCrete.module`, etc.) from the [Battle of Crete](http://www.moddb.com/mods/battle-of-crete) mod and renaming them to the existing files (`RelicCOH.module`, etc.). This causes the game to load with the mod's features, but as soon as I start a skirmish, I get a fatal AI error.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I have seen, modding on any games from the Mac app store do not succeed. I could be wrong about this game, though I have tried modding multiple other Mac app store games with no success.